# Excel sector charts group row

Tags: excel, charts

I have a bunch of values that are part of categories. Now I want to show the sum of each category in my chart. How can I group rows values of the same category in my chart only?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you can't achieve aggregate result without some data manipulation.
There are two ways to go on that issue.
First ,create a distinct categories, then sum-up the values by category using SUMIF Excel function, create your chart. The draw back of this method that if more categories added you'll have to add them manually.

[image: SUMIF example]

Second option, is to create a Pivot-table of your original data and only afterwards create pie chart.This option is more convenient, hence it is a scalable solution

[image: Pivot table example]

Have a great day